# how to disable remove the element after dragging in vue-draggable

Tags: drag-and-drop, drag, vuedraggable

I am working on vue draggable, the app has two list - list a and list b. I need to drag the elements from list a to list b.  When list b is added with element from list a, list a is also automatically removing the same element.

```
  <div class="h-96 overflow-y-auto">
    <draggable v-model="schema" class="flex-col space-y-1" :options="{sort: false, ghostClass: 'ghost', group: {name: 'schema', pull: true, put: false}}">
      <el-tag v-for="(item, index) in schema" :key="index" class="">
        <span >{{ item.name ? item.name + '(' + item.column + ')' : item.column }}</span>
      </el-tag>
    </draggable>
  </div>
```

What I need is after dragging is finished, list a won't remove the element.

how would I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with this

```
:group="{ name: 'group', pull: 'clone'}"
```